# throw new MongooseError.MissingSchemaError(name); MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "usermodel"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am getting Error "throw new MongooseError.MissingSchemaError(name); MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "usersmodel"."

Here userregistration.js

```
var mongoose=require("mongoose");
var Schema=mongoose.Schema;

var users= new Schema({
    firstname:String,
    secondname:String,
    apartmentname:String,
    block:String,
    floor:String,
    flotnumber:String,
    residencytype:String,
    ownername: { type: String, default:"" },
    password:{type:String,default:"password"},
    email:String,
    contact:{type:Number,default:0},
    address:String,
    role:{type:String,default:"user"},
    approvalstatus:{type:String,default:false}

});

module.exports=mongoose.model("users",users);
```

Maintaincemodel.js

```
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var Schema=mongoose.Schema;

var MaintenanceSchema= new Schema({
    name: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'usersmodel' }],
    Flat:{type:String},
    Squareft:{type:String},
    Month:{type:Number},
    Year:{type:Number},
    Amount:{type:Number},
    Paid:{type:String},
    Date:{type:Date,default:Date.now}
});

module.exports=mongoose.model('Maintenance',MaintenanceSchema);
```

Server.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema=mongoose.Schema;

var maintenancemodel=require('./public/models/maintenance.js');
var usersmodel=require('./public/models/userregistration.js');

app.get("/maintenance",function(req,res){

  maintenancemodel.find({})
  .populate('name')
  .exec(function(err,maintenances){
    if(err) console.log("error occures");
    else{
      console.log("the person name is",maintenances.name[0].firstname);
      res.json(maintenances);
    }
  })

});
```

I am successfully able to save the data into database But getting error when i was trying to populate data.

I have gone through multiple answers of same questions but i didn't find anything correct solutions for mine.

Comment: in MaintenanceSchema change  `name: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'usersmodel' }], `  to `name: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'users' }], ` and try.

Comment: Yeah ,Thank you ,Its working fine

Comment: copied to the answer to help anyone in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in MaintenanceSchema change name: `[{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'usersmodel' }],` to name: `[{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'users' }],`